# Riemannian Manifolds of Bounded Curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, curvature, negative-curvature

I am a complete newbie Riemannian Geometry with a particular application in mind so please excuse a lack of rigor in the question.

Suppose I have a manifold with sectional curvature everywhere negative and also lower bounded by $\kappa < 0$ (I think these are called Hadamard Manifolds). Between two point $x,y$ I consider two curves $\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t)$. I parallel transport a vector $v \in T_xM$ to $y$ along the two curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ giving me the vectors $v_1, v_2 \in T_yM$. I wish to say something about difference $v_1 - v_2$, in particular to bound $\|v_1 - v_2\|$. 
My bound can depend upon the lengths of the curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$.

Please provide a reference that could help me prove the above quantitative bound. From the little I have read it seems the quantity I care about is fundamentally related to the curvature tensor. In that case can I find an upper bound with respect to a bound on the curvature tensor? If yes can I relate the bound to the sectional curvature?

A general reference to understand these notions of curvature would be appreciated too.

Thanks

Comment: Parallel transport is an isometry, so $||v_1|| = ||v_2|| = ||v||$. This means that $||v_1 - v_2|| \leq 2||v||$.

Comment: I should have specified the kinds of bound I wish to achieve. So this bound does not depend on the curvature at all and if i move an infinitesimal amount the bound is not any better. I wish to have a bound that bounds the difference possibly with the curvature and the length of the curves.

Comment: When the closed curve $\gamma_1^{-1}\gamma_2$ is null-homotopic, i.e., it bounds some disk $D$;  the difference $v_1-v_2$ is estimated by the absolute value of the sectional curvature (-k) times the area of $D$, see Ambrose-Singer theorem. I ques, when the curvature is bounded above by some negative $K<0$ this area my be estimated further by the length of $\gamma_1^{-1}\gamma_2$.

Comment: Thanks Valeri. Could you provide a reference to the version of Ambrose Singer Theorem you are referring to? Your answer seems very relevant to my query. In fact the precise setting I have is indeed that I am parallel transporting the vector across a geodesic triangle, i.e. $\gamma_1$ is a geodesic and $gamma_2$ is two geodesics, i.e. a geodesic to an intermediate point $p$ from $x$ and then a geodesic to $y$ from $p$.

Comment: I think what you want is Theorem 13.6.4 of Andrew Pressley's "Elementary Differential Geometry." See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/parallel-transport-of-a-vector-along-two-distinct-curves

Comment: You can find this theorem (could be proved in one-line computation) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Ambrose.E2.80.93Singer_theorem , in Pressley's book as Alec Payne said (or in doCarmo), In your case the disk $D$ could be the union of all geodesics from $p$ to all points in $\gamma_1$ from $x$ to $y$ if all such geodesics unique (say all minimal). Then the area easy to compute (less than the are of the flat triangle with the same sides).

Comment: look also in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16850/curvature-and-parallel-transport/17028#17028

Comment: Valeri - Thanks for the answer and the links. I didnt find the Ambrose Singer theorem in doCarmo but I will look for further reading. A couple of quick follow up questions. One, I think as stated the scale seems to be wrong, i.e. do you think Area times the curvature represents the change in a unit vector around the loop? or may be a change in angle?

Comment: Since I need more space than available in comment - let me use answer option.

Comment: Here's a short note for a family of geodesics: http://www.deaneyang.com/papers/holonomy.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, (since I got this theorem myself and found out after that it is Ambrose-Singer) I mistaken exercise 4 in doCarmo p.105 for it. The proof looks like this: let $D$ be the image of a unit square with euclidean coordinates $0\leq s,t\leq 1$, and define $V(s,t)$ to be parallel along, say $s$-coordinate lines in $D$ and such that $D_t V(0,t)\equiv 0$. Then compute how the derivative of $V$ in $t$-direction changes along $s$-coordinate lines: it is $D_s D_t V = R(X,Y)V$ since $D_t D_s V \equiv 0$, and $s, t$ coordinate vectors commute - then $D_t V (1,t) = \int R(X,Y)V ds - D_t V(0,t)$, and further integral on $t$  of $D_t V(t,1)$ on $t$ from $0\leq t\leq 1$, gives the difference between $V(1,0)$ and $V(1,1)$ which is the difference between $V(0,0)$ and its parallel transport along the boundary of $D$ - check boundary conditions. To get scaling right note that $|X\wedge Y| ds dt$ equals the element of the area $dD$, where of course $X= \partial /\partial s$ and $Y= \partial /\partial t$.  In other words, we may integrate area element times $R(A,B)V$ over unit square where $A,B$ - pair of unit orthogonal vectors tangent to $D$.

Comment: Maybe you should add the isoperimetric inequality to get the kind of estimate the OP wants - see your comment above.

Comment: Sebastian Goette For the disk $D$ consisting of geodesics as in my comment above the isoperimetric estimate is directly following from Rauch type estimates for - in this case - Jacobi fields $\partial/\partial t (s,t)$ - easy. Otherwise - in general case - I am only guessing.